# When clicking back/front button on explorer, there is incorrect redirection. I am using play framework in scala

Tags: javascript, html, scala, web-applications, playframework

The back button on browser has incorrect redirection. The URI changes but the page remains the same.
My play framework project flow looks something like this:

**routes**

```
GET         /person/:height            controllers.ViewController.person(height: Int)
```

**controllers.ViewController.person**

```
def person(height: Int): EssentialAction = cached.apply(req => req.path, cacheDuration) {
    withoutLoginAction { implicit loginState =>
      implicit request =>
        Ok(views.html.person(Option(height)))
    }
  }
```

What is happening:

> URI: http://localhost:9000/person/height/78478

1. On clicking back URI changes to

> URI: http://localhost:9000/person/height

But the webpage remains same.

2. On clicking back again:

> URI: http://localhost:9000

But webpage is still same.

3. On clicking forward:

> URI: http://localhost:9000/person/height

and webpage is still same

I am just trying to navigate a simple webapp through back/forward buttons. How do I load the cached version of the page so that browser buttons works? The URI changes on pressing back but the page does not.I have gone through alot of tutorials but all of them change the URI manually and none of those tutorial uses back button.

**No request is being sent in network console on pressing back/forward button.**

Here is how the webpage looks:
[Screenshot of webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/61c93.jpg)

Comment: You didn't explain us what is happening when using back/forward button? Describe the navigation flow you have and what you'd expect instead. How the navigation is triggered? What does your page look like..? Impossible for us to answer without more details.

Comment: @GaëlJ Added more description.

Comment: What do you mean _webpage remains the same_? What if you hit F5? If you add logging in your backend, do you see the requests when using back button?

Comment: @GaëlJ The page remains the same as the URI before it. If I press back from http://localhost:9000/height/78478 , the URI changes but the content of the webpage is same as that of http://localhost:9000/height/78478. 

On pressing f5, the page content changes to as expected from that URI. 

How do I log the backend requests when using back button? via postate event listener? But in scala play, every request if through router .

Comment: You can add a log in the `Action` of each page, or just look in your browser Dev tools network panel to check the requests.

Comment: Also I just notice that you mention a route `person/:height` and a route `/height`. Which one is it??

Comment: @GaëlJ 
1) No request is being sent in network console on pressing back/front buttons.
2) It is person/height. Edited. Sorry.

Comment: Then you have something wrong in your JavaScript I guess which might be intercepting the navigation. This likely has nothing to do with your backend.

Comment: @GaëlJ
what should be my appraoch? How do I load the cached version of the page so that browser buttons works? 
I am new to webapps. Is it by default in other cases?